# split and write the files with AWK -Bash

Tags: linux, bash, awk

`INPUT_FILE.txt` in `c:\Pro\usr\folder1`

```
ABCDEFGH123456
ABCDEFGH123456
ABCDEFGH123456
BBCDEFGH123456
BBCDEFGH123456
```

used the below AWK command in `.SH` script which runs from `c:\Pro\usr\folder2` to split the file to multiple txt files with an extension of `_kg` based on first `8` characters.

```
awk '{ F=substr($0,1,8) "_kg" ".txt"; print $0 >> F; close(F) }'  ' "c:\Pro\usr\folder1\input_file.txt"
```

this is working good , but the files are writing in the main location where the bash is pointing. How can I route the created files to another location like `c:\Pro\usr\folder3`.

Thanks

Comment: Include the path as part of your `F` variable when you assign it (or concat the path when you perform the print.

Comment: The script you posted can't be working well as it contains an extraneous `'` that would produce a syntax error. Also, on linux `\f` means a formfeed character so using a path like `"c:\Pro\usr\folder1\input_file.txt"` can't be working for you. If you mean `"c:/Pro/usr/folder1/input_file.txt"` or similar then please [edit] your question to show the correct path(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following `awk` code may help you in same, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `awk`.

```
awk -v outPath='c:\\Pro\\usr\\folder3' -v FPAT='^.{8}' '{outFile=($1"_kg.txt");outFile=outPath"\\"outFile;print > (outFile);close(outFile)}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Creating an `awk` variable named `outPath` which has path mentioned by OP in samples. Then setting `FPAT`(field separator settings as a regex), where I am creating field of 8 characters starting from first character. In main program of `awk`, creating `outFile` variable which has output file names in it(1st field following by _kg.txt), then printing whole line to output file and closing the output file in backend to avoid "too many opened files" error.

Comment: Heh, heh.... well done. POSIX separators and all.

Comment: Thanks for the perfect solution. I have a little bit more requirement where I need to write the record from the 9th position and I used the below (because I know max record length which is 24000).awk -v outPath='c:\\Pro\\usr\\folder3' -v FPAT='^.{8}' '{outFile=($1"_kg.txt");outFile=outPath"\\"outFile;print substr($0,9,23992) > (outFile);close(outFile)}' Input_file . Is there any better option to avoid the hard coding of the length ?

Comment: @Krispy, Your welcome. You could create a variable in `awk` and you can give that variable in place of variable value in substr, by that way you need not to change whole code just change only variable value.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the destination folder as a variable to awk:

```sh
awk -v dest='c:\\Pro\\usr\\folder3\\' '{F=dest substr($0,1,8) "_kg" ".txt"; print $0 >> F; close(F) }' "c:\Pro\usr\folder1\input_file.txt"
```

I think the doubled backslashes are required.

Comment: `C:/Pro/usr/folder3/` probably should also work.

Comment: is it require to have the dest and input folders are different ? . Tried to replace the dest with a reference , it's failing . the reference $D_PATH is not expanding in dest folder.command ----> awk -v dest="$D_PATH' '{F=dest substr($0,1,8) "_kg" ".txt"; print $0 >> F; close(F) }' "$D_PATH/input_file.txt"